# Passing part of an url to another function in React

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way for React to take the back of an url user entered and pass it to a function? for example: www.site.com/foobar will pass the foobar to a function.
Essencially what i'm trying to do is to run a check on foobar being in my database inside the checker function, if not there display 404 page not found.

```
const NotFound = () => (<h1>404.. This page is not found!</h1>)

class App extends Component {

  checker : function(e){
    if(foobar exists)
      //load page with data
    else
      // {NotFound}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path='*' component={this.checker()} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `foobar` is an id?

Comment: no i'm planning on making a email verification system that generates a random token to put on the back of an url

Comment: yeah, like the route is actually `/something/:someId` and would handle `/something/somereallylongtoken`

Comment: depending on the version you're using, you can find what you're looking for here https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params

Comment: right so something like .com/abcdefg and i thought i can use '*' to just accept any value which i can pass to a function to apply logic to determine whether or not it's a token within my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand what I had written in my comment -

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
          <Route path='/' component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path='/:token' component={EmailValidation} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

class EmailValidation extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: false, valid: false }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    checkToken(this.props.params.token).then((valid) => {
      this.setState({ checked: true, valid })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { checked, valid } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        { checked
          ? <div>{ valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid' }</div>
          : <div>Checking token...</div> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this would be a good use case for an HoC which conditionally renders either the component you want or a 404 page - it would remove the binding between the 404 page and the email validate component (which are only sorta-kinda related)

if you're into using libraries, `recompose` has a bunch of nice helpers which can accomplish something like this for you.

something else you can do is use `react-router`'s `onEnter` callback/prop although, iirc, you can't directly access props from that callback.

Comment: It took me a while, but i managed to figure out how to pass the data along. Thank you for the help!